# Moving an object over a grid in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

My program created a grid which looks like this

```
- - - 
- - - 
- - -
```

I need to print an object over this grid, and this object needs to move around the grid. I need to place this object at random coords, before moving it.
For example:

```
- - -    - - -    - X -
X - - -> - X - -> - - -
- - -    - - -    - - -
```

I managed to  create the grid using a multi dimensional array but i don't know how to place the object on it. I thought of adding a line to place it "manually" right into the array, like that: `field[1][1] = 'X'` but obviously it's not going to work, since the array it's `int`, i'm thinking of doing it using pointers, any advice on how i could do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define GRID_WIDTH 3
#define GRID_HEIGHT 3

void view_grid(int field[GRID_WIDTH][GRID_HEIGHT]){
    int i,j;

    for (i=0;i<GRID_WIDTH;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<GRID_HEIGHT;j++) {
            printf("- ");

        }
        printf("\n");      
    }
}

int main() {
    int field[GRID_WIDTH][GRID_HEIGHT];
    view_grid(field);

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use char instead then?

Comment: Why don't you use an char Array and initialize it with '-' ? Than you can update the position and replace former 'x' with '-' and new position '-' with 'x'

Comment: Indeed changing field to char from int makes much more sense, i thought it was not going to work with the loop to initialize it. Now i need to understand how to put "X" over the grid as a variable

Comment: You could use a Curses library (ncurses on Linux, BSDs, Windows if using MingW, PDCurses if using Windows but not MingW) to draw the grid directly to the terminal window.